# Best Practice to Bind View Elements to ViewModel Xamarin forms

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

I have a Xamarin Forms project with a basic view and his respective viewmodel binding.

I'm trying to Bind View Elements to ViewModel as to work as easy as posible because some views will have a lot of elements as listviews, labels, buttons... with a lot of functionalities which changue te visual properties, for example visibility.

I think Binding every single property with a Binding as this example is a caos.

```
       <Label
        Text="{Binding PasswordLabel,Mode=OneWay}"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="Center" />
       <Entry
        Text="{Binding Password, Mode=TwoWay}"
        IsPassword="True"
        Placeholder="Password"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
        />
```

So i try to get views elements and bind with the correspondent object in viewmodel like Button _button = "button"

This way I can copy Web Component development, any component with their own responsability and reusable.

You think is a good practice my idea, and if is posible to do this binding?

Answer (score 1):

Although it seems caos as you mentioned that's the way it has to be. Your viewmodels represent your views but they are not the views this means there shouldn't exists any UI elements in these. Your viewmodels will be agnostic of the UI and they should only have properties and commands.

The viewmodels should be testable without relying on UI events. Your viewmodels doesn't know about Click, Tap, or any other event.

Comment: I think so MVVM pattern is not the way i want to work, what you think about adapt the xamarin utilities to a custom Component base framework? I think can be usefull to web developers

Comment: Finally i discover the best way (For me) My view just bind the UI element to a property on my ViewModel, for example, text , click Commands and i do a navigation static class, this way view have no logic about navigate or knowing other classes or modules. Every project on my solution is agnostic.